# VBA WorksheetFunction dynamic randbetween

Tags: excel, vba

hope all is well.

I am slightly stuck on a VBA function called randbetween in Excel.

Nature of the problem is that I need to create random numbers based on a bunch of other numbers, about 50,000 other numbers in total.

The random numbers I generate must be between 1 and X. X being the other numbers in column D1:D50,000.

As an example: if cell D1 contains the number 5, then I need to create a random number between 1 and 5 in Cell A1. then move on to D2,D3,D4.....etc and create random numbers for each one accordingly, A2,A3,A4...etc.

I tried to use the following but unfortunately the offset part doesn't work. I want to dynamically work through each cell.

the code is as follows:

```
r = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Offset(A1, n, 9))
'where n = 2
```

Most grateful for any help,

Comment: please show the wider scope of your code, not only one single line...

Comment: Thanks KazJaw, not sure exactly what I can add with regards to the wider scope to the code. For some reason Excel VBA doesn't seem to accept the offset function as part of a nested randbetween function. The range code Chris highlighted below seems to do exactly what is needed. This is part of a bigger code I am writing in Access database but I was stuck at the first part. Any thoughts on why original code didn't work would be useful. Is it just a quirk of Excel? Not sure. Thanks for coming back so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `OFFSET` is the wrong syntax.  You would need somthing like

```
Range("A1").Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset)
```

But there is a much better approach to achieve your stated goal.  Use `Range.FormulaR1C1`

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Define range
    Set rng = [A1:A50000]

    ' Put formulas into the range
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,RC4)"

    'optional, replace formulas with values
    rng.Value = rng.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I will have a look and get back asap.

Comment: The Range works perfectly. So my vba becomes: p = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Range("A1").Offset(2, 9))